# Network virtualization

Tags: java, networking, ilog

Does anyone know about the implementation of network virtualization in java, for details it's the embedding problem between the substrate network and the virtual request (both of them can be presented as graphs).

Thanks.

Comment: You can do network simulation in Java but I wouldn't suggest using Java to change the way TCP behaves on your machine.

Comment: Thanks anyway. but do u know the node embedding and link embedding ? furthermore, i have to optimize some functions to find the results by CPLEX IDE (OPL language)...

Comment: This sounds like ILOG specific terminology.  Have you asked them of a forum specific to ILOG?